# Grouping and splitting to avoid leakage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas `dataframe` where the data is arranged as follows:

```
        filename     label
0       4456723      0  
1       4456723_01   0
2       4456723_02   0
3       ab43912      1
4       ab43912_01   1 
5       ab43912_03   1 
...     ...          ...
```

I want to randomly split this `dataframe` in `training` and `validation` sets. Though if I do so, I will introduce a leakage because the files are images with slight variations but represented with different names, for example `ab43912, ab43912_01, ab43912_03`, are all same images with some variations.

Is there any efficient way to group these files and then make a split that doesn't introduce leakage?

Comment: why can't you merge the files and make a dataframe before you split?

Comment: [Build your First Image Classification Model in just 10 Minutes!](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/01/build-image-classification-model-10-minutes/) scroll down to see how they deal with the train / test splitting of the images.

Comment: @Trenton_M I know fair amount of ML. Think of this as the dataframe containing normal images and the augmented images part. As the dataset is huge, I can't navigate through the dataset and separate out images to avoid leakage

Comment: Is it enough to randomly sample ~80% of the unique `df.filename.str.split('_').str[0]`?

Comment: That might work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually select ~80% of the unique file handles randomly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'filename': list('aaabbbcccdddeeefff')})
df['filename'] = df['filename'] + ['', '_01', '_02']*6
```

---

```
# Get the unique handles
files = df.filename.str.split('_').str[0]

# Randomly select ~80%.
m = files.isin(np.random.choice(files.unique(), int(files.nunique()*0.8), replace=False))

# Split
train, test = df.loc[m], df.loc[~m]
```

---

In effect we got a 2/3-1/3 split because of the small N

`train`:

```
   filename
0         a
1      a_01
2      a_02
6         c
7      c_01
8      c_02
12        e
13     e_01
14     e_02
15        f
16     f_01
17     f_02
```

`test`:

```
   filename
3         b
4      b_01
5      b_02
9         d
10     d_01
11     d_02
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer